# reduce image size when displaying in template

Tags: python, django

I've already used `PIL` to reduce image size when saving an image,some thing like this:

```
image = Image.open(filename)
image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(filename)
```

now I want to show an image list in template,list of images is created in `views.py`:

```
for company in companies:
   list+='<img src="'+company.logo.url+'" />'
return render_to_response('index',{'list':list})
```

in `template`:

```
<span>{{list|safe}}</span>
```

Is it possible to reduce the size of images when showing them in template to load them quickly?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to reduce the size of images when showing them in
>   template to load them quickly?

Doing this dynamically will almost certainly be slower than just sending the image. When you save the image, just save another version that's smaller and serve that version in your list.

Comment: Why doesn't he write the code then if he's going to dictate minute implementation details like this? Just do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/955/) can be useful for what you are seeking. With this snippet you can solve the problem of resizing the images at `template` level. Also you can use a version that has done Ryan Fugger, which can be reached [here](https://github.com/rfugger/villagescc/blob/master/cc/general/templatetags/image.py). Hope it can help you.